# Define all constants as const references?

Tags: c++

Is there a best practice to define a constant? Here is a small example:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct mystruct {
    std::vector<double> data;
    mystruct() : data(100000000,0) {};
};

int main(){
    mystruct A;
    int answer = 42;

    const mystruct& use_struct_option_1 = A; // quick
    const mystruct use_struct_option_2 = A; // expensive

    const int& use_answer_option_1 = answer; // good practice?
    const int use_answer_option_2 = answer; // ubiquitous
}
```

Obviously, initializing `use_struct_option_2` that way is expensive because the copy constructor of `mystruct` is called whereas the way of initializing `use_struct_option_1` is quicker.
However, does the same apply to types such as integers?

From the code I've been locking at I can tell that

```cpp
const int use_answer_option_2 = answer;
```

is much more common than

```cpp
const int& use_answer_option_1 = answer;
```

Which one is preferable?

Comment: For  the `int` case, option 1 does not yield a constant value; it is a value that can't be changed via the name `use_answer_option_1`, but anyone can use `answer = 21;` to change what the reference refers to.  You have to decide whether that's what you want.  Similarly with the structure; do you, or do you not, care about someone modifying the data referred to by your 'constant reference'?  If it matters, then you need a copy, even if that means you add 800 MiB to your data space.  If it doesn't matter, then the constant reference to non-constant data is OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These do different things. For example, in the int case:

```
answer = 43;
cout << use_answer_option_1 << '\n';     // 43
cout << use_answer_option_2 << '\n';     // 42
```

In other words, option 2 makes a copy and option 1 doesn't.

Decide whether you want to make a copy or not (i.e. whether you want to see changes to the original initializer reflected in your reference).  The `mystruct` case is the same.